# Variable scope in php for a reference return?

Tags: php, scope, reference

> Variable scope (as defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php))
>
> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.

```
//a.php
<?php
class a {
 function &func () {
   $avar = array("one", "two", "three");
   return $avar;
}
?>
```

__

```
//b.php
<?php
class b {
 include("a.php");
 $ainstance = new a;
 var_dump($ainstance->func()); 
}
?>
```

The above code will Dump information about the variable as expected (I mean WRT the structure as formed in the function `func`).

My doubt is that,

- where are the variable stored when it is in the scope of a function?
- If it is on the call stack, then wont the variable be cleaned/destroyed when the function terminates?
- Since the variable is not getting destroyed (as per the code above), why is it not   getting destroyed or does PHP have a mechanism to save the variable (say in a heap)and return the reference to it.
- Does PHP have call stack at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All variables in PHP are `zval*`, that is, C pointers.

If you return by value, PHP will, in most cases, automatically copy the `zval*` and return that. If you return by reference, PHP will return the original `zval*`. In none of these cases does the returned `zval*` refcount reaches 0.

On the C side, well, when you return a variable, it returns a pointer to a `zval`, which is a C struct containing information about the variable (namely type, value, the refcount and a `is_ref` flag).

Since it's a pointer, it's not actually returning a local C variable, but a pre-allocated `zval` pointer, which points to the location of the actual `zval`. Unless that `zval*` refcount reaches 0 (i.e.: not storing the return value), the variable will still live until the end of the program.

Comment: Although I haven't understood it. Will go through [zval](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php). +1 for pointing to zval.

Comment: What you need to know is that when returning variables, PHP automatically returns a *copy* of the variable, unlike C per example, in which you have to make a copy yourself (e.g.: when returning a C string).